# PHP PDO prepare insert not inserting values inside data base, returning error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i trying insret new values in data base with PDO statement. and i got errors
cant understand what the probllems is...............
here the errors:

```
  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\wamp\www\OOPCMS_PROJECT\trancaction.php on line 68

  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\wamp\www\OOPCMS_PROJECT\trancaction.php on line 69

  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\wamp\www\OOPCMS_PROJECT\trancaction.php on line 70
```

and one more error :

```
    `Column 'name' cannot be null`
```

here is my code :

```
     $fruits = array( "name"=>"apple","color"=>"red","colories"=>"288");


     try {


     $db->beginTransaction();

     $sql = 'INSERT INTO fruit
     (name, colour, calories)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

     $sth = $db->prepare($sql);


      foreach ($fruits as $key=>$fruit) {


      $sth->execute(array(

       $fruit->name,
       $fruit->colour,
       $fruit->calories,
    ));
}



  $db->commit();


 } catch (PDOException $e) {


 $db->rollBack();
 echo $e->errorInfo[2];

 }
```

Comment: You don't need that `foreach` loop

Comment: you mean do this with bindvalue() ???

Comment: No. @oriol is stating that you have an array called fruits, but it only has one fruit of data, so unless that array is supposed to be an array of arrays you should not use the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the foreach loop:

```
$sth->execute(array(
   $fruits['name'],
   $fruits['color'],
   $fruits['colories'],
));
```

The problem is that you iterate `$fruits`:

1. First iteration (`$key` is `"name"` and `$fruit` is `"apple"`)

   You try to access `"apple"->name`, `"apple"->colour`, `"apple"->calories`, but `"apple"` is not an array.
2. 2nd iteration (`$key` is `"color"` and `$fruit` is `"red"`)

   You try to access `"red"->name`, `"red"->colour`, `"red"->calories`, but `"red"` is not an array.
3. 3rd iteration (`$key` is `"colories"` and `$fruit` is `"288"`)

   You try to access `"288"->name`, `"288"->colour`, `"288"->calories`, but `"288"` is not an array.

Also note that sometimes you use "c**a**lories" and sometimes "c**o**lories", and sometimes "color" but sometimes "colo**u**r".

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an variable named fruit that is an array, but later when you are accessing the values of fruit you are using it like an object.

Ditch the foreach loop and access the array like:

```
$fruit['name'],
$fruit['colour'],
$fruit['calories'],
```